# using a for loop rather than a large if statement to append info via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, while-loop

I have a table named bike_main with the columns "time" and "id", I use this table to get the busiest hour using mySQL

MySQL

```
$query = 'SELECT hour(date) AS h FROM bike_main GROUP BY h ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

This returns 17 in HTML

HTML

```
<div class="flip">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="flip-front blue circle">
            <h3 id="busierHour"><?php echo $row['h']; ?></h3>
            <p>is the busiest hour</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-back blue circle">
            <h3 class="notBusyhour"><?php echo $leastBusyDisplay['h']; ?></h3>
            <p>is the least busiest hour</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

To make this more user friendly, I would like to change the value from "17" to "5-6PM". Since this data is generated dynamically through the database, I will need to change any value from 1-24 to their respective hours(for example, 19 would need to be 7-8PM, since the current value of 17 can change at any time). The following code works:

jQuery

```
if ($('#busierHour').text() == '17') {
        $('#busierHour').text('5 - 6PM');
} else {
    console.log('hour not logged');
}
```

But rather than having one very large if statement I would like to have it run through a loop, which would detect the value and return it's respective value. I have tried:

JavaScript

```
var hour = 1;
var nextHour = hour+1;

while (hour < 24) {
    console.log('hour is ' + hour);
    console.log('next hour is ' + nextHour);

    if ($('#busierHour').text() == hour && hour > 12) {
        console.log('IF STATEMENT RAN!!');
        $('#busierHour').val(hour + '-' + nextHour + ' AM');
    } else if ($('#busierHour').text() == hour && hour > 24) {
        console.log('SECOND RAN');
$('#busierHour').val(hour + '-' + nextHour + ' PM');
    }
    hour++;
    nextHour++;
}
```

When the above JavaScript is run, the variables are returned correctly(hour is 1, next hour is 2, hour is 2, next hour is 3 etc.) but the console logs "IF STATEMENT RAN!!" after the console logs "next hour is 18". The console should be logging "SECOND RAN". None of the text changes in "#busierHour" either.

Comment: Why don't you do the transformation in PHP before you output it?

Comment: @pmandell I am a lot more experienced in JavaScript/jQuery than I am in PHP so I never thought of that.

Comment: @GGio can you elaborate? Was it the MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an associative array.

```
$hour = array(1=>'1-2am',2=>'2-3am',3=>'3-4am' .... , 17=>'5-6pm');

<h3 id="busierHour"><?php echo $hour[$row['h']]; ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just calculate it, something like

```
$('#busierHour').text(function(_, txt) {
    var hour = parseInt(txt, 10);
    var ampm = 'AM';

    if ( hour > 12 ) {
        ampm = 'PM'    
        hour = hour - 12;
    }

    return hour + ' - ' + (hour+1) +  ampm;
});
```

It's even easier if you do it in PHP before outputting the data

```
$timestamp = strtotime( $datestring_from_db );
$ampm_date = date("h.i A", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple calculation.

```
var busierHour = parseInt($('#busierHour').text());
var retString = '';

if(busierHour > 12){
   retString = (busierHour - 12) + ' - ' + (busierHour - 11) + 'PM';
}
else{
   retString = (busierHour) + ' - ' + (busierHour + 1) + 'AM';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your query format the result:

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(date, '%l')+
 '-'+
 DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%l%p') AS h 
FROM bike_main GROUP BY h ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```